# How do I handle file names with spaces when changing permissions for certain files in the current directory and all its subdirectories?

Tags: permissions, chmod, recursive

I am currently trying to set all files with extensions `.html` in the current directory and all its subdirectories to be readable and writeable<s>, and executable</s> by their owner and only readable (not writeable or executable) by groups and others. However, some of the files have spaces in their name, which I am unsure how to deal with.

My first attempt:

```
chmod -Rv u+rw,go+r '* *.html'
```

When I tried my first attempt, I get the following message:

```
chmod: cannot access '* *.html': No such file or directory
failed to change mode of '* *.html' from 0000 (---------) to 0000 (---------)
```

My second attempt:

```
find . -type f -name "* *.html" | chmod -Rv u+rw,go+r
```

I added a pipe operator in order to send the `find` command's output to `chmod`. However, when I tried my second attempt, I get the following:

```
chmod: missing operand after ‘u+rw,go+r’
```

After my attempts, I'm still confused on how to deal with spaces in file names in order to change set permissions recursively. What is the best way to deal with this issue? Any feedback or suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Why would you give yourself execute permission to html files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `-exec` predicate of `find`:

```
find . -name '* *.html' -type f -exec chmod -v u+rw,go+r {} +
```

(here, adding `rw-r--r--` permissions only as it makes little sense to add execute permissions to an html file as those are generally not meant to be executed. Replace `+` with `=` to *set* those permissions exactly instead of *adding* those bits to the current permissions).

You can also add a `! -perm -u=rw,go=r` before the `-exec` to  skip the files which already have (at least) those permissions.

With the [`sfind` implementation of `find`](http://schilytools.sourceforge.net/man/man1/sfind.1.html) (which is also the `find` builtin of [the `bosh` shell](http://schilytools.sourceforge.net/man/man1/bosh.1.html)), you can use the `-chmod` predicate followed by `-chfile` (which applies the changes):

```
sfind . -name '* *.html' -type f -chmod u+rw,go+r -chfile
```

(there, no need to add the `! -perm...` as `sfind`'s `-chfile` already skips the files that already have the right permissions).

That one is the most efficient because it doesn't involve executing a separate `chmod`  command in a new process for every so many files but also because it avoids looking up the full path of every file twice (`sfind` calls the `chmod()` system call with the paths of the files relative to the directories `sfind`  finds them during crawling, which means `chmod()` doesn't need to look up all the paths components leading to them again).

With `zsh`:

```
chmod -v -- u+rw,go+r **/*' '*.html(D.)
```

Here using the shell's recursive globbing and the `D` and `.` [glob qualifiers](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) to respectively include hidden files and restrict to *regular* files (like `-type f` does). Add `^f[u+rw,go+r]` to also skip files which already have those permissions.

You can't use `chmod`'s `-R` for that in combination with globs. Globs are expanded by the shell, not matched by `chmod`, so with `chmod -Rv ... *' '*.html` (note that those `*` must be left unquoted for the shell to interpret them as globbing operators), you'd just pass a list of `html` files to `chmod` and only if any of those files were directories would chmod recurse into them and change the permissions of all files in there.

Comment: Your [link for `sfind`](http://schilytools.sourceforge.net/man/man1/sfind.1.html) is broken (or the website is?)... and `sfind` is apparently not available through apt on debian or ubuntu. Where do you get it?

Comment: @Seamus, yes looks like sourceforge has discontinued the site after `@schily`'s death. You'll find clones here and there and you can still download the source from sourceforge.

Comment: Oh - so sorry to hear that. Sounds like it would be worth incorporating some of his ideas in `find`.

Answer (score 1):

"Filenames with spaces" calls for `find` and `xargs`. Read `man find xargs`, and do something like:

```
find . -type f -name '*.html' -print0 | \
    xargs -0 -r echo chmod u=rwx,g=r,o
```

Remove "`echo`" when it works for you.